# Are the Nvidia System Tools compatible with newer-generation graphics cards (like my GTX 560 Ti)?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I want to download and use [Nvidia System Tools with ESA suport](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia_system_tools_6.06.html). But on the "Supported Products" tab my GTX 560 Ti isn't listed. The product was last released on April last year, but it shows support for both the GTX 570 and 580 as well as the GTX 4x family. All sister cards of the GTX 560.

Has anyone successfuly ran this nvidia product with the GTX 560 Ti? Why wasn't this card included on the list of supported products?

Answer (score 4):

Nvidia stopped support for their Nvidia System Tools on April 2010 (almost three years ago at the time of writing this).  I attempted to use it with my GTX 560 Ti, and it **did not work correctly** (could only change clock speeds and not voltages, and it would not save any of my profiles properly).

*Fortunately*, you can use either of the freeware tools [EVGA Precision](http://www.evga.com/precision/) or [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/overview.htm) with any Nvidia graphics card (not just EVGA/MSI), allowing you to manually tweak the voltage, clock frequencies, and fan speeds of your graphics cards.

Both tools provide equivalent functionality, including modifying clock frequencies, voltages, and fan speeds (and can be set to automatically apply your profile on boot).

Answer (score 0):

The 560 Ti is based on the GF114 chip, while 570 and 580 are based on the GF110 (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_500_Series) for details).

It seems that this release only supports cards up to the GF110 (570, 580, 590) but nothing above it (560, 560 Ti or 550 Ti).

Therefore I would not install it since it is most likely that it will not work (best case) or crashes your computer (worst case).